# Authorization middleware exception in ASP.NET Core with Angular project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I have the following order of middlewares in my project:

**program.cs:**

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("MyOrigin");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

I studied a relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829324/endpoint-contains-authorization-metadata-but-a-middleware-was-not-found-that-su). I tried the following order:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("MyOrigin");

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

But I still get the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829324/endpoint-contains-authorization-metadata-but-a-middleware-was-not-found-that-su)
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint MaintenanceCMS.Controllers.ApiPmSchedualController.UploadNewPmFile
> (MaintenanceCMS) contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was
> not found that supports authorization.
> Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() in the application startup code. If there are
> calls to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...), the call to
> app.UseAuthorization() must go between them.

How can I fix this?

**Update:**
I'm using dotnet cli (.NET 7) in VS Code.

**Update 2: The whole program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Adding Configuration service to the project
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SqlServerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

#region Add CORS
builder.Services.AddCors((setup) =>
{
    setup.AddPolicy("MyOrigin", (options) =>
    {
        options.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin();
    });
});
#endregion

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]!)),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
    };
});

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("MyOrigin");

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Would you mind sending whole program.cs?

Comment: pardon me, but I was not able to reproduce the problem on my side. if I were you, I would have tried to delete and create project again!

Comment: Try this order: `UseHttpsRedirection().UseStaticFiles().UseRouting().UseCors(...).UseAuthentication().UseAuthorization() [...]`.  Also see [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I still get the following
> error:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware1
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint
> MaintenanceCMS.Controllers.ApiPmSchedualController.UploadNewPmFile
> (MaintenanceCMS) contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was
> not found that supports authorization. Configure your application
> startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() in the application startup
> code. If there are calls to app.UseRouting() and
> app.UseEndpoints(...), the call to app.UseAuthorization() must go
> between them. How can I fix this?

Based on your error message and shared code snippet, there might two main issues:

First of all, your `MaintenanceCMS.Controllers and ApiPmSchedualController` route defination, which you haven't shared within your question. Note that, Regarding, your MaintenanceCMS.Controllers. and ApiPmSchedualController route you need a route [[Route("[controller]")]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-route-constraints) specifier so that it doesn't collide with the Root Controller.

Another point is your [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order) and configuration went incorrect. Because, according to [authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#built-in-middleware) to be effective for endpoint routes, the call to UseAuthorization should appear between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints. In the absence of this, the fallback policy, if configured, will be used to authorize all requests.

However, your UseAuthorization has placed after routing but UseEndpoints is missing. In addition to this, CORS should be order after Routing and before Authetication. Therefore, you should do as following:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();       
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("MyOrigin");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "default",
     pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0001?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which would be helful for this kind of scenario.